# What does it mean by this "In Scala == and != methods check for value equaliy as opposed to Java where they check reference equality"

Tags: java, scala

I am learning scala and going over the fundamentals.

I couldn't understand what it means by "In Scala == and != methods check for value equaliy as opposed to Java where they check reference equality".

can someone give some example and try to explain in plain english?

Comment: You want to Google these terms; that's basic stuff explained all over.

Comment: Consider, for example, [What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java](/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Case 1 - [value classes](https://fossies.org/linux/misc/scala-sources-2.12.1.tar.gz/scala-2.12.1/spec/12-the-scala-standard-library.md)(`AnyVal`) and [case classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html)

With value classes in scala, `==` and `!=` do value check.

> Value classes are classes whose instances are not represented as
>   objects by the underlying host system. All value classes inherit from
>   class AnyVal.

all primitives in scala `Int`, `Float` etc are value classes.

```
scala> val quantity1 = 100
quantity1: Int = 100

scala> val quantity2 = 100
quantity2: Int = 100

scala> quantity1 == quantity2
res9: Boolean = true
```

Also, with `case classes`, `==` works implicitily.,

> Case classes are plain and immutable data-holding objects that should
>   exclusively depend on their constructor arguments

```
scala> case class Item(name: String, quantity: Int)
defined class Item
```

Now, compare two items just by `==` will check if all the values in item are equal.

```
scala> Item("Jacket", 100) == Item("Pants", 10)
res0: Boolean = false

scala> Item("Jacket", 100) == Item("Jacket", 100)
res1: Boolean = true
```

### Case 2 - Ref classes in scala(`AnyRef`) and java classes(`java.lang.Object`)

But with `Ref` classes in scala and all Java classes, if you do `==`, it checks the instance reference instead of values until you write your own [equals method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609/432903).

#### Java Example,

```
static class Item {
        String name;
        int quantity;

        Item(String name, int quantity){
            this.name = name;
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Item item1 = new Item("Jacket", 100);
        Item item2 = new Item("Pants", 10);
        Item item3 = new Item("Jacket", 100);

        System.out.println(item1 +"==" + item2 + " " + (item1 == item2)); //false
        System.out.println(item1 +"==" + item3 + " " + (item1 == item3)); //false
    }
```

the `==` comparison result would be

```
com.somepackage.EqualityTests$Item@1b28cdfa==com.somepackage.EqualityTests$Item@eed1f14 false
com.somepackage.EqualityTests$Item@1b28cdfa==com.somepackage.EqualityTests$Item@7229724f false
```

Where `1b28cdfa` is the instance ref for `item1`. You see `item1` and `item3` have same data but `==` gives false because they are two different instances referring to two different addresses.

To mimick what scala does on value class `==`, implement your `equals` method as below and do manual equality check.

```
static class Item {
    String name;
    int quantity;

    Item(String name, int quantity){
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Item i = (Item) obj;
        return this.name.equals(((Item) obj).name) && this.quantity == ((Item) obj).quantity;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Item item1 = new Item("Jacket", 100);
    Item item2 = new Item("Pants", 10);
    Item item3 = new Item("Jacket", 100);

    System.out.println(item1 +".equals(" + item3 + ") " + (item1.equals(item3))); //true
}
```

#### Same with scala Ref classes, that `==` compares the reference if equals method is not implemented

```
scala> class Store(name: String){} //equivalent to Store extends `AnyRef`
defined class Store

scala> val store1 = new Store("a")
store1: Store = Store@2063c53e

scala> val store2 = new Store("a")
store2: Store = Store@61c76850

scala> store1 == store2
res7: Boolean = false
```

But if there's your own `equals` method in scala Ref classes then == refers to your `.equals` method.

Example,

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Store(val name: String){
    override def equals(that: Any) : Boolean = {
         val thatStore = that.asInstanceOf[Store]
         name == thatStore.name
    }
}

scala> new Store("JWN") == new Store("JWN") // calls s1.equals(s2)
res1: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Both "in scala, == and != do value check" and "But in Java, if you do ==, it checks the instance reference instead of values until you write your own equals method" are wrong (first is sometimes, second is always).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov thats right, it depends whether the object I create is value class or ref class in scala.

Comment: you are right. my answer had type on case class example, which does not need to extend `AnyVal`.

Comment: case class Store(name:String, zipcode:String)

Store("AlamedaTarge", "94501") == Store("AlamedaTarge","94501")

Comment: I dont know what you are saying. `Store("AlamedaTarge", "94501") == Store("AlamedaTarge","94501")` should be true, as `Store` is a case class. but if you make it `AnyRef` then to access the params declare them as `val` and override equals method. Example. `class Store(val name:String, val zipcode:String) extends AnyRef {}`